# Efficient way to make multiple clickable areas on a static image component (in React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, overlay

I'm trying to figure out the best way of making clickable areas for a static image (which is a component). The goal is not to show users those clickable areas with any click effects. After users click the correct areas, the score will increment.

What I'm thinking to make `div`s that overlay the image. But there are many random objects that I need to consider. I might need to a lot of math (mainly ratio problems) for each `div` I'm making.

I'm also trying to use html `map` tag. So far, I don't see anything clickable. I don't get errors either.

What's the most efficient way of approaching this problem?

Here is my code:

```
//my static image component

import React from "react";

const BackgroundImage = ({ src, name }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <img className="backgroundImage" src={src} useMap={name} alt={name} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default BackgroundImage;

//the map components that I can pass in different values to make different clickable areas

import React from "react";
import BackgroundImage from "./BackgroundImage";

const Mapper = ({
  src,
  name,
  target = "_self",
  alt = "none",
  title,
  coords,
  shape,
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <BackgroundImage src={src} useMap={name} />
      <map name={name}>
        <area
          target={target}
          alt={alt}
          title={title}
          coords={coords}
          shape={shape}
        />
      </map>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Mapper;

//the component with game logic: upon clicking correct clickable areas, users will earn scores (i.e. 3 areas to click to get it right; scores ranging from 0/3 to 3/3) after 10 seconds passed, then it automatically move on to the next page

import React from "react";
import zoomcall from "../images/zoomcall.png";
import BackgroundImage from "./BackgroundImage";
import Timer from "./Timer";
import LeftArrow from "./LeftArrow";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import CorrectClicks from "./CorrectClicks";
import Mapper from "./Mapper";

const ZoomCall1Countdown = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* <BackgroundImage src={zoomcall} usemap="zoomcall" /> */}
      <Timer />
      <CorrectClicks />
      <Link to="/readingtheroom">
        <LeftArrow />
      </Link>
      <Mapper
        src={zoomcall}
        name="zoomcall"
        title="11"
        coords="0,22,295,196"
        shape="rect"
        style={{ backgroundColor: "red", border: "5px,solid,red" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ZoomCall1Countdown;
```

For `Mapper`, I'm thinking replicate this component to add more clickable areas. Right now, it's only one to try out.

Answer (score 0):

Map should be perfect to add clickable areas on top of image.

`<map>` should be rendered before `<BackgroundImage>` producing HTML similar to [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map).

```
const Mapper = ({
    src,
    name,
    href = 'about:blank',
    target = "_self",
    alt = "none",
    title,
    coords,
    shape,
}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <map name={name}>
                <area
                    href={href} // URL to open when clicked
                    target={target}
                    alt={alt}
                    title={title}
                    coords={coords}
                    shape={shape}
                />
            </map>
            <BackgroundImage src={src} name={name} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

`href` prop was added for URL to open when area is clicked.

And also `BackgroundImage` should reference map by using attribute like `usemap="#zoomcall"`:

```
const BackgroundImage = ({ src, name }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <img className="backgroundImage" src={src} usemap={`#${name}`} alt={name} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

**P.S.**

Alternatively SVG vector image can be used instead of img+map because it supports hyperlinks in it.

Read [this article](https://medium.com/@gianpaul.r/adding-clickable-links-to-an-svg-image-file-f254e0f6b71a) to learn how to add links to SVG.

Or use SVG editor that supports it.

For example [this SVG with links](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vburlai/chat-design-demo/master/demo/src/img/Chat-design-demo.svg) was created using Google Drawings.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answers. I implemented the code but I wonder how to test it out. I still don't see anything on the console. Do I need to use useEffect along inside of Timer component? When the timer is on, users need to click on clickable areas then the scores will be updated.

Comment: I haven't implemented href yet. Maybe that's why nothing happened. The problem is I don't want redirect to anywhere else except on the same page. Does it mean I need to put the path of the image inside of href?

Comment: @coderonpointe There is a visual difference between having `href` attribute and not having it. You can use `#` value for href (`href="#"`) so it stays on the same page and does nothing.